# Is it possible to write a class that can store lvalue references or objects exlusively?

Tags: c++, reference, rvalue-reference

I'm sick of passing all my objects by value and then moving, or overloading on lvalues and rvalues. I'm trying to write a class that can either store an lvalue reference or a normal object if an rvalue is passed into the constructor.

Here is the skeleton:

```
template<typename T>
class ref {
private:
    T* m_ptr = nullptr;
    std::optional<T> m_obj;
    bool is_lvalue = true;
public:
    ref(T& lvalue_ref) : m_ptr{ &lvalue_ref } {}
    ref(T&& rvalue_ref) : m_obj{ std::move(rvalue_ref) }, is_lvalue{ false } {}

    T& get() {
        return (is_lvalue) ? *m_ptr : *m_obj;
    }
};
```

I want to use this class with functions like `void foo(ref<bar> r) {}`, so any function taking `ref<T>` does not make any copies. Unfortunately, you have to check every time if a reference/object is stored whenever you get the value, and `std::optional` default constructs its object and we pay for that even if we are storing an lvalue. Is it possible to create a class that stores either an lvalue reference, or an object, and still be able to have a function taking `ref<T>` be able to bind both lvalues and rvalues of T to it?

Comment: A reference is not an object. It can't be "stored" in another object like `vector`, `array`, `class` etc.

Comment: You can use/store `std::cref` or a pointer though.

Comment: Or there is std::reference_wrapper. But having a "convenience" wrapper like this, could be tricky some objects will get copied implicitly making you lose track of lifetime of objects. And in big projects that can lead to surprises.

Comment: @user12002570 I know a reference is not an object, that is why I want to move my rvalue into an object so that I don't have an evaporated temporary. Otherwise, if an lvalue reference is passed in I want to store a pointer to that lvalue.

Comment: @PepijnKramer can reference_wrapper store an object if you pass an rvalue to it, so that there aren't lifetime problems?

Comment: @TwistedBlizzard  I mean use reference_wrapper to replace m_ptr. But as said I think this is not a good idea.

Comment: _I'm sick of ... overloading on lvalues and rvalues._ Can you use C++23?

Comment: @PaulSanders I can, but how does C++ 23 fix this?

Comment: Overloading on lvalues and rvalues usually involves writing different logic. An opaque class that may store an object or reference an object stored somewhere else is asking for a trouble with lifetime management. ¿How do you even intend to use such a class? This question seem to be an XY problem.

Comment: I may be misinterpreting a bit, but this looks like along the lines of a concept discussed in this blog, in which the author provides an implementation of an object that can store exactly one-of a value, const-reference, or non-const reference; it could be applicable here? https://www.fluentcpp.com/how-to-store-an-lvalue-or-an-rvalue-in-the-same-object/ -

Comment: This feels like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). A parameter of type `const T&` can bind to both `T&` and `T&&` without the need to overload. If the parameter has to be non-const, then usually either working with an rvalue reference is a logical error or it calls for a different implementation (i.e. an overload). This isn't 100% of the time, but being "sick of" the remaining cases makes me wonder (not 100% sure) if the wrong solution (Y) is being applied to the real problem (X).

Comment: @TwistedBlizzard *"When T&& binds to const T& you get a copy."* ??? Since when? *(Actually, a `T&&` cannot bind to a `const`, but I'll presume you just phrased that backwards. For a function `f(const T&)` called via `f(g())` it's the `const T&` that binds to something.)*

Comment: @JaMiT I'm sorry, I don't know why I thought that.

Comment: @TwistedBlizzard https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/cpp23-deducing-this/ (not sure if other compilers support it yet)

Comment: I agreen with @JaMiT this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Indeed, the question features the skeleton of  a possible solution to a not well defined problem: you write _"I'm sick of passing all my objects by value and then moving, or overloading on lvalues and rvalues"_. How? Show an example of code that led you to think you need a solution to a problem. Are the context where you overload on rvalue ref and lvalue ref generic contexts? Or are you referring to functions taking concrete values? None of these facets is explained in the Q.

Comment: Alternative link to the XY problem: https://xyproblem.info/

Answer (score 0):

I'll first quote my comment, so everybody can have a full view of my... view.

> I agreen with @JaMiT this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Indeed, the question features the skeleton of a possible solution to a not well defined problem: you write *"I'm sick of passing all my objects by value and then moving, or overloading on lvalues and rvalues"*. How? Show an example of code that led you to think you need a solution to a problem. Are the context where you overload on rvalue ref and lvalue ref generic contexts? Or are you referring to functions taking concrete values? None of these facets is explained in the Q.

But I still think some guessing can be attempted.

From

> I'm sick of passing all my objects by value and then moving, or overloading on lvalues and rvalues.

and

> want to use this class with functions like void `foo(ref<bar> r) {}`, so any function taking `ref<T>` does not make any copies.

I assume you have many functions taking args by value, and/or many functions overloaded for `&` and `&&`, in either case the type(s) of the arg(s) being **concrete** (otherwise, if those functions were templated, I'd have expected at least a mention of a forwarding reference in the body of your question).

To avoid the copies, I think you'd go (or you are going already) for a solution like this, which is repeated for several functions, where you duplicate not just the interfaces in a header,

```cpp
// foo.hpp
#pragma once
#include "Bar.hpp"
void foo(Bar&);
void foo(Bar&&);
```

but also the business logic in the implementation files:

```cpp
// foo.cpp
#include "Bar.hpp"
void foo(Bar& x) {
    business_logic(x);
}
void foo(Bar&&) {
    business_logic(std::move(x));
}
```

a typical client code looking like this,

```cpp
// main.cpp
#include "foo.hpp"
#include "Bar.hpp"
int main()
{
    foo(Bar{3});
    Bar x{3};
    foo(x);
}
```

If that's the case, one solution could be to just template the functions and *impletement them in the cpp file, **together with the two explicit instantiations you need***:

```cpp
// foo.hpp
#pragma once
template<typename T>
void foo(T&&);
```

```cpp
// foo.cpp
#include "Bar.hpp"
template<typename T>
void foo(T&& t) {
    business_logic(std::forward<T>(t));
}
template void foo(Bar&);
template void foo(Bar&&);
```

Notice that my toy example has the same length in both cases, but there are some differences between the two. In my proposed solution,

- there is *only one* implementation shared for rvalues and lvalues, so you are not duplicating business logic;
- you can just `std::forward<T>` the argument to other functions, whereas in the "manual" overload case you have to write `std::move` in one overload and nothing in the other;
- a test could have the benefit of exercising `foo` with a simpler type than `Bar` by just instantiating `foo` for a `BarForTests` mock type.